# Can Phonegap work with google maps ?

Tags: cordova, google-maps-api-3, gis, cordova-2.0.0

I use cordova 2.2.0 & I want to make a gis application that checks users location to choose the closeset one. 
Can I make this with phonegap ... and would it be supported on IOS6 & Android ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [GoogleMaps in PhoneGap](http://zsprawl.com/iOS/2012/03/using-phonegap-with-google-maps/). Also check out the [PhoneGap GeoLocation API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_geolocation_geolocation.md.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Google Maps Plugin for PhoneGap / Cordova](https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin) helps you to control Google Maps SDK from JavaScript.

[image]